# Knockout Update TextArea with Multiple Binding

Tags: html, sql, knockout.js

Still learning...  I have an area that has parameters which are bound to other fields.  Within this area, I'd like for the user to be able to adjust any parameter, or custom edit the SQL Query, or even paste their own and click "Get Data" to execute the SQL command.

Ideally, this area would look to be the same box (either using one textArea, swapping two textAreas out, or doing this text/textArea swap).  My biggest hurdle is getting the updates to stick.  I suspect it has something to do with the dependentObsevable, but I have not be able to break the trial/error cycle.  For now, I have the "Get Data" button, wired up to display the adjusted text in a box below, rather than actually send the command.

I also believe that the selected value logic should be in the "selected" observable as a function, but just wasn't sure how to make that happen.  Your eyes and feedback are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/camcguir/ng56u/6/).

HTML:

```
     <b style="width: 800px; height: 163px;" data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: queryBuilder(), click: edit">&nbsp;</b>
     <textarea style="width: 800px; height: 163px;" data-bind="visible: editing, value: queryBuilder(), hasFocus: editing, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></textarea>
     <button data-bind="click: update">Get Data</button>
```

View Model:

```
  var giveBack = ko.observable("nothing");
  //Query Builder for the text area
  self.queryBuilder = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
      //var giveBack = ko.observable("nothing");
      if (self.selected() == 0) giveBack = self.getTransByHourQuery;
      if (self.selected() == 1) giveBack = self.getTransByHourQuery2;         
      return giveBack;
  }, this);


  self.update = function(){
      return self.query(giveBack);
  };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_My biggest hurdle is getting the updates to stick_"? If you mean to retain user selection after a post then you need to write code to pass them back after page reload.

Comment: Nah... I'd like for the user to be able to choose an option from the drop down and have a pre-populated value in the text-area.  Then, if the user decides that they want to adjust the 'given' parameters, they can, and the contents of the text area will update accordingly.  Lastly, if the user decides that they want to make changes to the text or quite honestly replace the contents of the text area they can.  Long and short, the final value that is in the text area is the value that I want to capture and send. Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 separate observables, one for the non-edit mode, another for edit mode.

```
  self.rawQuery = ko.observable();

  self.queryBuilder = ko.computed(  function() {
      var q1 = self.getTransByHourQuery();
      var q2 = self.getTransByHourQuery2();
      var raw = self.rawQuery();

      var selected = self.selected();

      switch( selected ) {
          case "0":
              // Set current "raw" to this query
              self.rawQuery(q1);
              return q1;
          case "1":
              // Set current "raw" to this query
              self.rawQuery(q2);
              return q2;
          default:
              return raw;
      }
  });
```

Clear the selected option when going to edit mode

```
  self.edit = function () {
      self.editing(true)
      self.selected(undefined);
  };
```

Add a placeholder to the combo box so we can clear the selected observable and get the rawQuery value into the queryBuilder.

```
<select data-bind="options: querySelector(), optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selected, optionsCaption: 'select...'"></select>
```

Move the click binding to the td element, not the b element so you can click on something when rawQuery is empty and selected is blank

Because I'm using a computed, you need to change the b element text binding to drop the *()* from text binding value

```
<b style="width: 800px; height: 163px;" data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: queryBuilder">&nbsp;</b>
```

And switch the textarea's value to rawQuery and remove the valueUpdate binding.

```
<textarea style="width: 800px; height: 163px;" data-bind="visible: editing, value: rawQuery, hasFocus: editing"></textarea>
```

I also added **enable: selected** to each input's data-bind in the top row.

---

Now you have 2 observables, you should be able to get manual updated from the rawQuery back into the top input boxes, but it will be tricky.  The best bet is to use regular expressions to try and match your parameters.

The code below works, but it is a little hacky ;)

First attach a "match" Regex pattern off each observable that are used as parameters.  We'll use it later.

```
  var buildParam = function( value, matchRx ) {
      var result = ko.observable(value);
      result.matchRx = matchRx;

      return result;
  };

  self.startDate = buildParam("02/01/2014 12:00 AM", /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2} (?:AM|PM)/);
  self.endDate = buildParam("03/30/2014 12:00 AM", /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2} (?:AM|PM)/);
  self.serviceType = buildParam("401", /\d+/);
  self.channelID = buildParam("101", /\d+/);
```

Next create a function to build a query definition

```
  var buildQueryDef = function() {
      // Get the arguments, first is the query, all the remaining are observables
      var theArgs = [].splice.call(arguments, 0);

      // Start building the object.  shift the first arg off directly off as the query
      var def = {
          query: theArgs.shift()
      };

      // The remaining elements in the array now all observables.

      // Create a computed to convert the parameters placeholders to real values.
      def.transformed = ko.computed( function() {

          var result = this.query;
          var index = 0;
          theArgs.forEach( function(item) {
              // replace {@p1} with first observable value, and so on
              result = result.replace( new RegExp( "\{\@p" + (index++) + "\}", "g" ), item());
          } );

          return result;
      }, def);

      // Create a function that matches text back to the original query.
      def.doMatch = function( text ) {

          // Convert any special regex control characters to literals and convert spaces to '\s+'
          var src = this.query.replace( /[\(\)\[\]]/g, "\\$&").replace( /[ ]+/g, "\\s+");
          var index = 0;

          // Replace the parameter placeholder with the regex from the parameter observable
          theArgs.forEach( function(item) {
              src = src.replace( new RegExp( "\{\@p" + (index++) + "\}", "g" ), "(" + item.matchRx.source + ")");
          } );

          // Match whole string, allow trailing spaces
          src = "^\s*" + src + "\s*$";

          return { src: src, matches: text.match( new RegExp(src) ) };
      }.bind(def);

      // Update the observables from the match set.
      def.setObservables = function(matches) {
          // Ignore first match as it's the entire string
          for(var index = 1; index < matches.length; index++) {
              theArgs[index-1](matches[index]);
          }

      }.bind(def);

      return def;
  };
```

Build each query def from the query SQL.  I have updated your original SQL to include parameter placeholders where you were concatenating strings ( hope you don't mind ! )

```
  self.queryDefs = {
      '0': buildQueryDef("SELECT " +
          "TABLE_ID as TABLE, " +
          "DATEPART(HH,CREATE_DATE) AS HOUR, " +
          "CAST(CREATE_DATE AS DATE) AS DATE, " +
          "COUNT(TRANSACTION_ID) as TRANSACTION_COUNT " +
          "FROM " +
          "[TRANSACTION_SUMMARY] " +
          "WHERE " +
          "CREATE_DATE BETWEEN '{@p0}' AND '{@p1}' " +
          "AND SERVICE_TYPE = {@p2} " +
          "AND TABLE_ID= {@p3}", this.startDate, this.endDate, this.serviceType, this.channelID ),
      '1': buildQueryDef("SELECT " +
          "TABLE_ID as TABLE2, " +
          "DATEPART(HH,CREATE_DATE) AS HOUR2, " +
          "CAST(CREATE_DATE AS DATE) AS DATE2, " +
          "COUNT(TRANSACTION_ID) as TRANSACTION_COUNT2 " +
          "FROM " +
          "[TRANSACTION_SUMMARY] " +
          "WHERE " +
          "CREATE_DATE BETWEEN '{@p0}' AND '{@p1}' " +
          "AND SERVICE_TYPE = {@p2} " +
          "AND TABLE_ID= {@p3}", this.startDate, this.endDate, this.serviceType, this.channelID )

  };
```

Notice the correlation between the parameter index and the order of the observables passed into the function, also the "key" for each entry corresponds to the "id" of the select boxes backing store.

The queryBuilder computed can now use the queryDefs object, using the selected() observable value as the key.

```
  self.queryBuilder = ko.computed(  function() {

      var selected = self.selected();
      if ( self.queryDefs[selected] ) {
          var result = self.queryDefs[selected].transformed();
          self.rawQuery(result);
          return result;
      } else
          return self.rawQuery();
  });
```

Add a couple of subscriptions to editing and rawQuery to run the matching system above

```
  self.editing.subscribe( function(isEdit) {
      if ( !isEdit && ( self.rawQuery.isDirty != true )) {
          // force a refresh if the observable wasn't changed
          // otherwise the queryDefs won't match back up
          self.rawQuery.notifySubscribers(self.rawQuery());
          self.rawQuery.isDirty = false;
      }
  });
  self.rawQuery.subscribe( function(text) {
      if ( self.selected() ){
          return;
      }

      self.rawQuery.isDirty = true;

      for(var query in self.queryDefs) {
          var def = self.queryDefs[query];
          var result = def.doMatch(text);

          if ( !result.matches )
              continue;

          self.selected(query);
          def.setObservables( result.matches );

          return;
      }
  });
```

The isDirty flag is used to detect when a user clicks into the "edit" but doesn't make a change.  In that scenario the rawQuery subscription will not fire and the select box will not re-select a defined query, so we manually force a notification when editing goes back to false is required.

In have create a new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eB2J9/) with these updates so you can play with it.

Comment: This looks awesome.  My apologies; I've been away for a few days.  First, your taking the time to look at this so closely, is very much appreciated.  Over the next few days, I'll check it out more closely, and let you know how it fits in.  Once again, thank you.  Just seeing this helps provide more perspective on working with knockout, in general.